# Kafka + Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka

Facing issue while consuming the messages. I am having 5 brokers and 5 partitions with 4 replicas.I have created 3 consumers and trying to consume the messages by connecting to Zookeeper. But I am getting all the messages on single consumer and not getting the messages to rest of the consumer.
Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Can you give code examples on how did you create 3 consumers ? How did you set the properties ?

Answer (score 3):

[...] By having a notion of parallelism—the partition—within the topics, Kafka is able to provide both ordering guarantees and load balancing over a pool of consumer processes. **This is achieved by assigning the partitions in the topic to the consumers in the consumer group so that each partition is consumed by exactly one consumer in the group.** [...]

cf: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers